# Google Drive API /files slow response

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to ask for help/ideas on the issue I will describe below.

Our iOS app allows users to access their Google Drive files.

We use Changes API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes). The main pre-condition to using this API is to build a local DB that holds the snapshot of the user's Drive file tree and the token. To initially fill the DB we must request the list of all files from user's Drive. Getting the list of all files (with metadata) takes too long for many of our users. This is the issue I want to address.

We request files with the series of Files requests (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). Most requests are plain `files?q=trashed%20%3D%20false`.

For example, at my own private Google Drive:

- 69K files
- initial request of all files takes 5+ minutes with my current network speed (Download 527 Mbps, Upload 417 Mbps; `ping www.googleapis.com` – 40–45 ms)
- ~150 requests
- each request brings information about ~460 files
- each request takes around 2-2.5 seconds

Sometimes I observed requests to take up to 6 seconds, which means that getting all files list took 15 minutes at my account.

If I look at the Developer Console, the latency is below 0.1s

Many of our users have Drives far bigger than mine. Standard iOS app user's session is not long enough to complete the initial request. We do save every intermediate page token so that all data received during single app session is not lost if user leaves the app – next session we will keep downloading data from the last saved token. But still there're some cases when our app needs the DB to be filled out with data before starting some operations – in that case our users see "Pending..." progress and they complain that our app is slow.

So, questions:

1. is it possible to improve the described request speed/latency?
2. maybe there's some quota that we are missing and it can be changed?
3. maybe someone can advice a more effective way of getting all files list?

P.S. We could potentially reduce the amount of requests. We have to perform some double checks for Shared with Me folders as we observed that sometimes request of all files doesn't list all files from Shared folders. That's a bit of a side story, and I don't think this will dramatically improve situation for us. I can provide more details on the actual set of requests we perform if necessary.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a much smaller scale. I'm doing a simple Files.list with q set to "'a folder ID' in parents". It takes around two seconds; my drive only contains about 13,000 files. The parent folder I'm listing only has about 250 files. Viewing a list of those files the the Drive web interface takes a fraction of a second. What's up with this API??

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning all the fields - I would assume so since the only query param provided is trashed=false as the query param.  Do you need all the fields?  Can you try to reduce the query to only return the fields you really care about (using a field mask) and see if that improves your performance?

Comment: Actual set of file fields we use is:
 `name,fileExtension,id,capabilities,sharedWithMeTime,mimeType,createdTime,modifiedTime,size,ownedByMe,webViewLink,quotaBytesUsed,md5Checksum,shortcutDetails,parents,resourceKey`

Just for the sake of experiment I narrowed it down to:
 `name, fileExtension, id, mimeType, parents`

Unfortunately, this didn't help much – response time is still ~2 seconds.

Comment: Here's an example of actual request URL, maybe something will catch your eye:

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken%2C%20files%28name%2CfileExtension%2Cid%2CmimeType%2CcreatedTime%2CmodifiedTime%2Cparents%29&pageSize=1000&pageToken=~%21%21~AI9FV7QVSk3_79ZWUQc3jXK1X2N_VE_gOO-Vef_UNlqDgXGdHeBpfZslcrRxXPyszDJfxhkUQBmRlhs6ZrJqHcKDQu2a4hDG0FAQ_DBEJRL_BpvT-BdnDUnqGBdSk8R9olV5f0eYbOna27fH9c2u7hmfA06wBVTmrg1sd3Z2k9jbrSOJfKHQqkMZmRSxD09nue5MOCpjtxlu1EctRMnOTr5FG7ke1K_x79Y8SaYpdf5zoOD7Xpb1Nknv0p_LK9V64YZVVQYqB3qAm-lvfFZoKpmuF3-B8xcMXPMsccvFWYLg5AX_zIblQ9Ahg-JYfW4PeosNDeAwE8qa&prettyPrint=false&q=trashed%20%3D%20false